# How to Install ASP.NET Core Runtime 7.0.0-rc.1 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, .net-7.0

I have .NET6 runtime installed on Ubuntu 22.04

```
$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And tried to install ASP.NET Core Runtime 7.0.0-rc.1 but without any success.
Any idea, please?

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

Comment: Are you getting any error? Could you please confirm `SDK` has installled successfully ? In addition, which command did you executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for interesting.
So, I ended up with this solution

1-

```bash
curl https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/0857e86d-4206-4c14-b814-e5e3424f8396/6e1113fce778ef9ff69eb2ffefd6de76/aspnetcore-runtime-7.0.0-rc.1.22427.2-linux-musl-x64.tar.gz -o aspnetcore-runtime-7.0.0-rc.1.22427.2-linux-musl-x64.tar.gz
```

2-

```bash
mkdir dotnet7-7.0.100-rc.1
```

3-

```bash
tar xvf aspnetcore-runtime-7.0.0-rc.1.22427.2-linux-musl-x64.tar.gz -C dotnet7-7.0.100-rc.1
```

4- (Optional; sure, if not exist before)

```bash
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/dotnet
```

5-

```bash
sudo cp -R dotnet7-7.0.100-rc.1 /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet7-7.0.100-rc.1
```

6-

```bash
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet7-7.0.100-rc.1 /etc/alternatives/dotnet7rc1
```

7-

```bash
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet7-7.0.100-rc.1/dotnet /etc/alternatives/dotnet
```

Ref: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Answer (score 0):

> And tried to install ASP.NET Core Runtime 7.0.0-rc.1 but without any
> success. Any idea, please?

Tough [`.NET 7 RC 1`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) has been released. However, regarding `Linux Runtime`  compatibility there is not official guideline yet. Furthermore, here is the [`open GitHub thread`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7716) you can post your issue.

Up to now, for `Ubuntu 22.04` `dotnet-runtime-6.0` has official instructions where you should consider following scenarios:

1. [`Clean machine`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699) (`Haven't installed dotnet before`)
2. [`Mixed-state`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699) (Installed dotnet before but want to update`)

**Note:** Please consider your state first, depending on the scenario command might changed. For example, if you encounter any error on executing this command `udo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0` that scenario, you should replace with below command.

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

**Suggested Commnad:**

As per your scenario, you could follow below command as suggested [`here`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699#issuecomment-1269368779):

```
sudo apt remove dotnet*
sudo apt remove aspnetcore*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list*
sudo apt update
sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
```

You could check details here in [official GitHub thread](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699#issuecomment-1249494185).

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.100-linux-x64-binaries and follow the instruction. Just installed on Ubuntu 22.04

Do not forget to update the shell profile as indicated in the instructions

p.s. I started the service and in my case I had to replace /usr/bin/dotnet with /root/dotnet/dotnet

```
[Unit]
Description=PotokWebRoot

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/PotokWebRoot
ExecStart=/root/dotnet/dotnet /var/www/PotokWebRoot/PotokWeb.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=potok
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issues when wanted to migrate the 2 projects from .NET 6 to .NET 7 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with frustrating errors like `dotnet-sdk-7.0` NOT found or it is not release candidate (also got the same errors for `aspnetcore-runtime-7.0` and `dotnet-runtime-7.0`).

As I understood later I had machine with [Mixed-state according to this link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699).

The only solution which helped me it is **Solution 3** from [Microsoft documentation Ubuntu 22.04 troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup#solutions) (don't know why Solution 2 did not work for me). Below I wrote what I do:

1. Removed installed .NET 6 with the next commands

```
sudo apt remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

2. Created the `/etc/apt/preferencesList` file with `sudo nano` and paste the next content in it:

```
Package: dotnet-sdk-7.0
Pin: origin "packages.microsoft.com"
Pin-Priority: 999
```

3. Ran the next command in console which installed `dotnet-sdk-7.0` correctly

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

4. Updated `net6.0` with `net7.0` in `ExecStart` for service files related to the 2 projects (in `/etc/systemd/system/` folder)